# Reverse for 'post_share' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)\\/share\\/$', 'blog\\/post_share\\/$']

Tags: django

Before, you guys give me that "use the search tools" kind of speech. Yeah, I already did it, and to no avail. Anyways, I have been scratching my head for the last two days trying to figure out why I keep getting this error" Reverse for 'post_share' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\/(?P[0-9]+)\/share\/$', 'blog\/post_share\/$']"

I am using Django 2 and I am reading the book Code for Django by Example book by Antonio Mele.

### Forms.py

```
class EmailPostForm(forms.Form):
name = forms.CharField(max_length = 30)
email = forms.EmailField()
to = forms.EmailField()
comments = forms.CharField(required = False, widget = forms.Textarea)
```

### Views.py

```
def post_share(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, id = post_id, status = 'published')
    sent = False

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = EmailPostForm(request, POST)

        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            post_url = request.build_absolute_uri(post.get_absolute_url())
            subject = '{} ({}) recommends you reading "{}"'.format(cd['name'], cd['email'], post.title)
            message = 'Read "{}" at {}\n\n{}\'s comments: {}'.format(post.title, post_url, cd['name'], cd['comments'])
            send_mail(subject, message, 'sample@gmail.com', [cd['to']])
            sent = True
    else:
        form = EmailPostForm()
    return render(request, 'blogg/shared.html', {
                                            'post': post,
                                            'form': form,
                                            'sent':sent
                                            })
```

### urls.py

```
app_name = 'blog'

urlpatterns = [

    path('post_list', views.post_list, name = 'post_list'),
    path('post_detail/<int:year>/<int:month>/<int:day>/<str:post>', views.post_detail, name = 'post_detail'),
    path('post_share/', views.post_share, name = 'post_share'),
    # re_path(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/share/$', views.post_share, name='post_share'),
    path('<int:post_id>/share/', views.post_share, name='post_share'),
]
```

### details

```
{% extends 'blogg/base.html'%}

{% block title %} {{ post.title }} {% endblock %}

{% block content %}
    <h1> {{ post.title }}</h1>
    <p>Published {{ post.publish }} by {{ post.author }}</p>
    {{ post.body|linebreaks }}
    <p>
        <a href="{% url 'blog:post_share' post.id %}"> Share Post </a>
    </p>
{% endblock %}
```

### Error

```
NoReverseMatch at /blog/post_detail/2018/04/24/simple-test

Reverse for 'post_share' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)\\/share\\/$', 'blog\\/post_share\\/$']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/blog/post_detail/2018/04/24/simple-test
Django Version:     2.0.4
Exception Type:     NoReverseMatch
Exception Value:    

Reverse for 'post_share' with arguments '('',)' not found. 2 pattern(s) tried: ['blog\\/(?P<post_id>[0-9]+)\\/share\\/$', 'blog\\/post_share\\/$']

Exception Location:     C:\Dev\blog\lib\site-packages\django\urls\resolvers.py in _reverse_with_prefix, line 632
Python Executable:  C:\Dev\blog\Scripts\python.exe
Python Version:     3.6.4
Python Path:    

['C:\\Dev\\blog\\src\\mysite',
 'C:\\Dev\\blog\\Scripts\\python36.zip',
 'C:\\Dev\\blog\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Dev\\blog\\lib',
 'C:\\Dev\\blog\\Scripts',
 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\Lib',
 'c:\\program files (x86)\\python36-32\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Dev\\blog',
 'C:\\Dev\\blog\\lib\\site-packages']

Server time:    Tue, 24 Apr 2018 12:40:59 +0000`
```

Comment: Please show the full traceback (which will show where the error is occurring) and the `Post.get_absolute_url()` method and `details.html` template (which is where the error might be occurring).

Comment: Also, your `post_share` view requires the `post_id`, so the URL pattern `path('post_share/', ...)` isn't going to work. Remove it.

Comment: The arguments '(",)' part of the error message is telling you that you're not giving an argument as part of the url.  Look at that.

Comment: Done, i have updated it

Comment: {% extends 'blogg/base.html'%} should this not be {% extends 'blog/base.html'%} not blogg

Comment: Well, actually my app is called blogg.

Comment: at  Alasdair  Done, I removed it, is that okay if I leave the "path('<int:post_id>/share/" ?

Comment: Yes, you should keep `path('<int:post_id>/share/, ...)`. The traceback tells you that the error is occurring on `/blog/post_detail/2018/04/24/simple-test`, but you haven't shown the `post_detail` view that handles that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the `to` and `name` variables at the start of the function like this..

```
def post_share(request, post_id):
    post = get_object_or_404(Post, status='published', id=post_id)
    sent = False
    to = ""
    name = ""   
    ...........
```